# PI3 b+ - NOOBS 2.7/2.8/3.0

Tags: pi-2, noobs

I have a problem with my new Raspberry. I have 3 devices to play a video from a website 24/7. One of them freezes many times after hours.

1. Temperature is about 50°C,
2. I use Chromium v65,
3. use VNC,
4. no any other special applications,
5. not connected any usb devices,
6. use LAN cable,
7. tested from different ports,
8. tested with Wifi,
9. changed memory card,
10. changed adapter,
11. and there is no error in log!!!
12. installed updates!
13. try without updates!

I have only one comment: If I turn off the VNC service on Raspberry PI then it is working...

I have installed different versions of NOOBS 2.7,2.8 but same problem. When I use newer version of it, then (the Chromium is above v75 and) it couldn't play video from the websites because the videoplayer is black.

The other 2 devices are working fine... Any idea or suggestion please ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't "install … NOOBS" - it is an OS installer. We don't know what you did (or where you got these old versions). You have not posted any diagnostics. Install Raspbian.

Comment: SORRY - you have right: I installed from NOOBS 2.7 for example, Raspbian Deb: 9 - 4.9.80-v7 
from offical website: http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS/images/

Comment: Why are you using Chromium to play a video - use a video player such as omxplayer.

Comment: Anything older than NOOBS 3.0 is **too old** for a RPi 3B+.